# How to run multiple json requests in set up script?

Tags: soapui, load-testing

I am new to soap UI tool and i want to create test data for a test case by running multiple json requests? At the moment i am creating test case by adding test data creation as steps of the test cases.[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSnsb.png)

ex: Add some questions to an active event. so my test API calls are create event and active event.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new testcase, which contains the REST requests you want to run when starting up.

Then DISABLE it. Thus SoapUI / LoadUI won't execute it when running the TestSuite.

In each of your OTHER TestCase setup script, you add this:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("name of the testcase you want to run").run(context, false)
```

That should run your disabled testcase via the setup script.

Comment: Thanks, But i want to run set up script from test case level as each of my test cases has different set ups. I tried same script in test case level and it wont work.  is there a similar script i can run in test case level?

Comment: @Ruwi : I'll modify my response to reflect your needs... (Done.)